# How to create a Mono from a completableFuture

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, project-reactor, completable-future

I am trying to wrap `CompletableFuture` inside a Reactor `Mono` type in order to simplify my transform operations. Project Reactor is more convenient in general! I am working inside an AWS Lambda function and I am invoking AWS services such as S3, SQS, etc... using the new AWS Java SDK 2.x version. This new SDK allows to make asynchronous calls to AWS services and returns CompleteableFuture objects.

For example:

```
S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder().build();    
Mono.fromFuture(s3AsyncClient.getObject(b -> 
b.bucket(bucketId).key(objectKey), AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()).subscribe()
System.out.println("stuff");
```

The problem is, when my main code invokes the `CompletableFuture` `(s3AsyncClient.getObject)`, suddenly the execution thread switches to the CompleteableFuture thread and my main method that invoked the Mono returns before the CompletableFuture completes.

Basically, from the example above, the `"stuff"` string gets printed before the `s3AsyncClient.getObject` completes.

How can I make sure the Mono and the `CompletableFuture` executes within the same thread or how do I make sure my lambda doesn't terminate before the `CompletableFuture` have completed?

For those wondering, I only get this behavior when I deploy my code remotely to AWS Lambda. I don't experience this behavior locally...

Answer (score 8):

`//.thenApply will wait for your future to complete first and then return Mono<T>
Mono.fromFuture(yourCompletableFuture.thenApply(x -> x.doSomething);`

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by saving a CompletableFuture in Mono and then blocking it, and after completing CompletableFuture, I got the final answer. As follows:

```
  CompletableFuture completableFuture = new CompletableFuture();
  Mono mono = Mono.fromFuture(completableFuture);

  mono.block(Duration.of(30000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
  //
    Something is done elsewhere in the project or program, and after receiving 
    the response, the response method can be completed/error the 
    completableFuture.
  //
  mono.toFuture().exceptionally(ex -> { do stuff});
  mono.toFuture().thenApply(result -> {do stuff});
```

Comment: unless in a test, but blocking a Mono/Flux is not a good practice