# TarArchiveInputStream with Java Reactor

Tags: java, reactor

Currently I'm dealing with a TarArchiveInputStream as this :

```
private Mono<Employee> createEmployeeFromArchiveFile() {

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        return new Employee();
    })
    .flatMap(employee -> {

        try {
            TarArchiveInputStream tar =
                    new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/myarchive.tar.gz"))));
            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            tar.read();
            while ((entry = tar.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.getName().equals("data1.txt")) {
                    // process data
                    String data1 = IOUtils.toString(tar, String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    if (data1.contains("age")) {
                        employee.setAge(4);
                    } else {
                        return Mono.error(new Exception("Missing age"));
                    }
                }
                if (entry.getName().equals("data2.txt")) {
                    // a lot more processing => put that in another function for clarity purpose
                    String data2 = IOUtils.toString(tar, String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    employee = muchProcessing(employee, data2);
                }
            }
            tar.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("Error while streaming archive"));
        }

        return Mono.just(employee);
    });

}

private Employee muchProcessing(Employee employee, String data2) {
    if (data2.contains("name")) {
        employee.setName(4);
    } else {
        // return an error ?
    }
    return employee;
}
```

Firstly, is this a correct way to process the archive file with Reactor ? It works fine, but it seems like synchronous business inside a flatMap. I haven't found a better way.

Secondly, I don't know how to handle the function `muchProcessing(tar)`. If that function triggers errors, how would it return them in order to be dealt appropriately as a `Mono.error` ? Since I want this function to return me an employee.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the task inside the `flatMap` as a `CompletableFuture` and convert it to a `Mono`. Here's a link on how to do that:

[How to create a Mono from a completableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154979/how-to-create-a-mono-from-a-completablefuture)

Then, you can abstract it out as:

```
.flatMap(this::processEmployee).doOnError(this::logError).onErrorResume(getFallbackEmployee())
```